# Post via git repository

Tags: plugins, git, github

I want to be able to post via a git repo. For example I have a repo named "blog" which contains these files:

```
first_post.md
second_post.md
another_post.md
```

I want all these files to appear in my blog like normal posts. I also want to be able to edit the files from the admin panel too (not only via git).
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You haven't given much to go on. And this strikes me ans a pretty limited case, which may not fit the guidelines in the [faq]. Look for the part about "too localized"

Comment: Is it a custom git or open service or install with a API, like Github with json api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments on this question stated, there is far too little detail in your post and it is far too localized of a question for this forum, but here is a general idea of what a project of this nature would require:

You would need to utilize the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/) to dynamically pull new posts, as well as to enable modifying of the content and reposting back to GitHub.

You would also need to develop a plugin that handles the integration of a GitHub repo with the WordPress posts using the [WordPress API](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_API%27s).

In general, posts are stored in a database. You would need to override (or supplement) this behavior with support for pulling from a new source (GitHub).

All that said, this is a massive job for what seems like a very small payoff. If you don't mind me asking, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thought that it would be easier. It's just more convenient for me. I may write this plugin.

Comment: Do you mind explaining your reasoning? Just curiosity, really. If it has to do with the free hosting aspect, [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) might be an easier option that doesn't require a bunch of extra custom configuration.

Comment: Also, if this answered your question, I'd appreciate you clicking the check box. Thanks! :)

Comment: It is just easier and better to edit the posts via github. I also have a backup of my posts, in case something breaks.